# Query result into array in Laravel 6

Tags: arrays, chart.js, laravel-6

I have this result from my database:

```
year  column1  column2
2018    11         7
2019    24        12
2020    15        13
```

I want put the result in arrays like this:

```
['2018','2019','2020']
[11, 24, 15 ]
[7, 12, 13]
```

I need make a stacked bar graph, i'm using charts.js:

```
$chart01 = new BarChart;
$chart01 ->type('bar')
         ->labels(['2018','2019','2020']);

$chart01->dataset('Column1', 'bar', [11,24,15])
                    ->options(['backgroundColor' => ['#58D3F7','#58D3F7','#58D3F7']]);

$chart01->dataset('Column2', 'bar', [7,12,13])
                    ->options(['backgroundColor' => ['#5882FA','#5882FA','#5882FA']]);

$options = [];
$options['scales'] = [ 'xAxes' => [ ['stacked' => true] ], 'yAxes' => [ ['stacked' => true] ] ];
$chart01->options($options);
```

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pluck` method to achieve what you want.

For instance:

```php
$models = App\Model::all()

$models->pluck('year')->toArray(); // [2018, 2019, 2020]
$models->pluck('column1')->toArray(); // [11, 24, 15]
$models->pluck('column2')->toArray(); // [7, 12, 13]
```

You can read more about `pluck` here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck